# Precision Difference: NumPy Object Array vs. Float Array

Tags: python, numpy, precision, eps

I understand that the precision of a NumPy float array's element is limited by the machine epsilon.

However, I'm struggling to understand why specifying the array's datatype as a Python object, instead of as the default float, results in the array storing the precise value I feed it. Can someone please explain this behaviour?

The code below illustrates the rounding error associated with the float datatype, and the change in precision when using the object datatype.

```
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(precision=64)

MyArray = np.empty(2)
MyArray.fill(0.442)
print(MyArray)

# [ 0.442000000000000003996802888650563545525074005126953125
#   0.442000000000000003996802888650563545525074005126953125]

MyArray_precise = np.empty(2, dtype = object)
MyArray_precise.fill(0.442)
print(MyArray_precise)

# [0.442 0.442]
```

I'm running a 32-bit Python 2.7.12 installation on 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just a matter of display formatting you're seeing. You're not actually getting a more precise number either way; it's just that the `precision=64` display setting you set doesn't apply to object arrays. It only applies to arrays of floating-point dtype.

If you print more digits of the contents of `MyArray_precise`:

```
print(format(MyArray_precise[0], '.64'))
# 0.442000000000000003996802888650563545525074005126953125
```

You'll see that it's not actually any better than the other array.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the issue you with floats is a matter of display, not precision.

But there is a different issue with long integers.  Python has a long integer type that does not have a `numpy` dtype.

```
In [87]: x=12312312312311231231241241242342
In [88]: x
Out[88]: 12312312312311231231241241242342
```

This is Py3.  Py2 shows it as `12312312312311231231241241242342L`

```
In [90]: np.array([x])
Out[90]: array([12312312312311231231241241242342], dtype=object)
In [91]: np.array([x],int)
....
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```